# MYSQL Query to find the RANK

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables PLAYER and MATCHES

```
CREATE TABLE PLAYER 
(
id int PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255),
salary int
);
INSERT INTO PLAYER values(1,'MOHIT',1000);
INSERT INTO PLAYER values(2,'MNOP',2000);
INSERT INTO PLAYER values(3,'ABC',100);
INSERT INTO PLAYER values(4,'XYZ',10);

CREATE TABLE MATCHES 
(
id int,
player_id int,
scores int
);
INSERT INTO MATCHES values(1,1,100);
INSERT INTO MATCHES values(2,2,52);
INSERT INTO MATCHES values(3,3,10);
INSERT INTO MATCHES values(4,1,200);
INSERT INTO MATCHES values(5,1,300);
```

Can anyone tell me MYSQL query to find the number of matches MOHIT played to score a double century(200 runs).

I have used the below query but is giving me SQL error.

**QUERY:-**

```
 SELECT FIND_IN_SET(Select m.id from MATCHES m
  JOIN PLAYER p
  on p.id=m.player_id
  WHERE p.name='MOHIT'
  AND m.scores>=200 
  ORDER BY m.scores limit 1,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
  SELECT m.id from MATCHES m 
  JOIN PLAYER p
  on p.id=m.player_id
  WHERE p.name='MOHIT'
  ))) AS RANK;
```

In this query i am trying to find the first match_id for which MOHIT scored a double century and then find the RANK of that match_id among all the matches he has played.

The expected Output should be 2 as MOHIT played 2 games to score 200 or more than 200 runs.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, could you please edit your question with expected output.

Comment: @SonamTripathi :done

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct in understanding, requirement could be achieved using MYSQL COUNT()

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS no_of_match 
FROM   matches m 
       JOIN player p 
         ON p.id = m.player_id 
WHERE  p.NAME = 'MOHIT' 
       AND m.scores >= 200;
```

Comment: No your solution is incorrect because you are finding the no of matches in which MOHIT scored >=200 but the requirement is to find the no of matches he played to score first 200. which is count of match id (1,4)

Comment: No, I am only considering match_id 4 and 5 with condition p.NAME = 'MOHIT'

Comment: Please read ur query. You are getting the output as 2 because MOHIT has scored >=200 in 2 matches. I have changed the dataset and now the result should be 3 but ur query will still return 2 --- Check here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1762cb/1

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
SELECT p.name ,sum(case when scores>=200 then 1 else 0 end) AS no_of_match_200 
    FROM   matches m 
           JOIN player p 
             ON p.id = m.player_id 

   where p.name ='MOHIT'
   group by p.name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1762cb/7

```
name    no_of_match_200
MOHIT   2
```

Comment: The query should return 3 in this case - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3c260b/1. But it is always returning 2.

Comment: @Sunny you said about double century thats why condition was 200 if you change condition in case statement that will show you 3

Answer (score 0):

IN this solution the inner query works out a cumulative score and a count of the matches played, the outer query finds the earliest match where the cumulative score meets your boundary condition.

```
select p.name,min(s.matchesplayed) matchesplayed
from player p
join
(

select m.player_id,
        (select sum(m1.scores) from matches m1 where m1.player_id = m.player_id and m1.id <= m.id) sumscore,
        (select count(m1.scores) from matches m1 where m1.player_id = m.player_id and m1.id <= m.id) matchesplayed
from matches m

) s on s.player_id = p.id
where  # p.name =  'mohit' and 
        sumscore>= 200
group by p.name;
```

In this case my query will find any player.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
select count(*)
from players p join
     matches m
     on p.id = m.player_id
where p.name = 'Mohit' and
      m.id < (select min(m2.id)
              from matches m2 
              where m2.player_id = m.player_id and
                    m2.score >= 200
             );
```